# android how to connect with Bluetooth printer?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-printing

Actually i already make an connection between my android device and bluetooth printer i have  few problems in it

Bluetooth connection is made out in one fragment.When i go back into fragment once again i need to recreate the connection.But i want to create a connection once and reuse it untill Unpair the device.

BluetoothChartServices.java

```
public class BluetoothChatService {

private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
private static final boolean D = true;
private static final String NAME = "IPrintmarvel";
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private final Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; 
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; 

public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}

private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;
}

public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

public synchronized void start() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

            if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    if (mAcceptThread == null) {
        mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mAcceptThread.start();
    }
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected");
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}

      mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}
public synchronized void stop() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

public void write(byte[] out) {
    ConnectedThread r;
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    r.write(out);
}

private void connectionFailed() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

private void connectionLost() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");
        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothChatService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

ConnectionFragment.java

```
Button print;
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = 
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
private static final boolean D = true;
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";

public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

private String mConnectedDeviceName = "";
BluetoothDevice device;
public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
private Handler mHandlern = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_connect:
            //mBtp.showDeviceList(this);
            Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getContext(), DeviceListActivity1.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_dunpair:
            try {
                Method m = device.getClass()
                        .getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
                m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the device MAC address
                String address = data.getExtras()
                        .getString(DeviceListActivity1.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
                 device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
              //  mTitle.setText(address.toString());
                // Attempt to connect to the device
                mChatService.connect(device);


            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupChat();

            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
                Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    }
}
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        // Otherwise, setup the chat session
    } else {
        //if (mChatService == null)

        setupChat();
    }

    //  TextView txtbt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TXTBTSTATUS);
    if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        //text.setText("Status: Enabled");
        //   txtbt.setText("BT:Enabled");
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");
    if (mChatService != null) {
        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
            // Start the Bluetooth chat services
            mChatService.start();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
    if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");

}
  private void setupChat() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");
    mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(getApplicationContext(), mHandlern);
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- bluetoooooth -");
}
   print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    Printxt.append("--------------------------------------" + "\n");
                Printxt.append("         Thank you ! Visit Again    " + "\n");
                Printxt.append("**************************************" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n");
                sendMessage(Printxt.toString());
        }
     });
         private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    else{
       // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);
    }
}
```

What i wanna do.Once i pair with the bluetooth device it will not ask another time to pair with the device. if the fragment will open or close is not matter.connection will be destroyed only unpair the device or close the app

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with bound service (intent service has it own background thread)
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Bind the service to main activity and create a class which has service as dependency, then you may control the service how you want to.